# Apache2 subsite url configuration

Tags: apache2

I have one main website and several subsites like :

```
/var/www/mainsite
/var/www/subsite0
/var/www/subsite1
/var/www/subsite2
...
/var/www/subsiten
```

With my actuel apache2 configuration, these url are available :

```
http://myip/mainsite
http://myip/subsite0
http://myip/subsite1
http://myip/subsite2
...
http://myip/subsiten
```

But I would like url path this :

```
http://myip/mainsite
http://myip/mainsite/subsite0
http://myip/mainsite/subsite1
http://myip/mainsite/subsite2
...
http://myip/mainsite/subsiten
```

Is it possible to get this result without change directories emplacement ? Only change the apache configuration ?

Thanks ! 
My apache version : 2.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You should make redirects in your apache2 virtualhost configuration (It depends what system you use) or simply in the web root directory's .htaccess file. For example:

```
#/var/www/.htaccess
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mainsite/subsite0/(.*)$ subsite0/$1 [L]
```

This will point all mainsite/subsite0/* request to the subsite0/*.
Make sure the apache2 mod_rewrite module is enabled. Again, the commands are depends on your system.

More info:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html